# Case Instance Id not getting updated when process is restarted in Camunda

Tags: java, api, workflow, camunda, camunda-modeler

Following code is executed to restart a process in Camunda. But case instance id is null for the new process. What else is required for getting the case instance id?

```
List<HistoricTaskInstance> sql = processEngine.getHistoryService().createHistoricTaskInstanceQuery()
                .processInstanceBusinessKey(caseId).orderByTaskName().desc().list();
        HistoricTaskInstance historicTaskInstance = sql.get(0);
        logger.info("{}", historicTaskInstance);
        logger.info("{}", historicTaskInstance.getCaseInstanceId());
        runtimeService.restartProcessInstances(historicTaskInstance.getProcessDefinitionId()).initialSetOfVariables()
                .startBeforeActivity(historicTaskInstance.getTaskDefinitionKey())
                .processInstanceIds(historicTaskInstance.getProcessInstanceId()).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtimeService is for ProcessInstances only ... for CMMN Cases, use the CaseService ... but: you will see that there is no restart method ... and as camunda stopped further development of CMMN cases, there probably won't be ...

I believe your best choice is to somehow start a new case and try to provide as much state from the previous instance as possible ... and before you ask: I have never done that before and won't be of any help doing so.